# PHP ternary operator giving an unexpected T_echo

Tags: php, echo, ternary-operator

My ternary is returning an error. Am I forgetting some basic rule or quirk about using PHP ternaries with echos?

```
isset($tag) ? 
    echo '<a href="#">' . $tag['firstname'] . '</a>' : null;
```

The above ternary returns the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /classes/Photo.php on line 216
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `if` here?

Comment: IMHO a ternary statement is used as a single line expression, why not use an `IF` statement?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you should write like this:

```
echo (isset($tag) ? '<a href="#">' . $tag['firstname'] . '</a>' : '');
```

Comment: Interesting, so each part of a ternary can only create a value, it can't execute a function?

Comment: It can execute a function (even such that doesn't return any value). `echo` is simply not a function - it's a language structure like `isset`, `list` or `empty`.

Comment: @Crozin well isset, list or empty are **all** functions. echo is the only one of those that is a structure.

Comment: @Neal They're *not* functions - even the manual states that. The fact that most of them use the function-like syntax don't make them functions.

Comment: @Crozin if there is a return, it is usually defined as a function.

Comment: @SLAYER in 2016 youre answer still saved waisting a lot of time

Answer (score 2):

Use print() instead of echo when you need to display text within an expression.